# c# IS-IS Net ID calculator

Tags: c#, network-programming

I'm currently working as a Network Administrator, and at the moment we're in the process of adding new routers to our network, among this, we need to set up some routing protocols, and we're using a protocol called IS-IS, which needs a NET ID.

So I thought I'd try and make a calculator, now I've made most of it, apart from the really useful part lol.

A net ID looks like this: 49.0001.1720.1600.1001.00

Breaking it up; **area prefix:** 49.0001

**Ip Adress:** 1720.1600.1001

and a **NSEL suffix:** .00

In my calculator I've got 5 textboxes, 4 of which are for the ip address in this instance, the 5th Textbox is the CIDR value, which is not used for this function.

Say the user puts the following into the boxes **[172]-[16]-[1]-[1]**
I somehow need to pad these values with zeroes, so it becomes this: 
**172.16.1.1 ---> 172.016.001.001**

And after I've done that, I need to rearrange the "bits" into 3 groups of 4 digits, so it becomes this: **172.016.001.001---> 1720.1600.1001**

The rest I can do, but the rearranging of the actual ip and the padding, I havent had any luck with.. 
I tried doing

`string tb1 = textBox1.Text.PadLeft(4, '0');`

but this just adds the zeroes and it doesnt rearrange the values.

I've looked at doing

`var strIP = new StringBuilder();
 strIP.Append(textBox1.Text);`

But still havent found out how to rearrange

**TLDR:** **How do I make 172.16.1.1 become 1720.1600.1001** when each of the original groups are from individual textboxes.

ps. sorry for the lenghty post, thought I had to explain myself to make myself understandable.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Assuming your text boxes values are named `octet1` .. `octet4`, you can combine them into a `List` to work on them, then concatenate them and split them:

```
var octets = new List<string> { octet1, octet2, octet3, octet4 };

var octetStr = string.Join("", octets.Select(o => o.PadLeft(3, '0')));
var ans = octetStr.Substring(0, 4)+"."+octetStr.Substring(4, 4)+"."+octetStr.Substring(8);
```

I am using LINQ to pad each one to 3 digits, but you could do them individually instead.

```
var octet1Padded = octet1.PadLeft(3, '0');
// and so on...
var octetStr = octet1Padded+octet2Padded+octet3Padded+octet4Padded;
var ans = octetStr.Substring(0, 4)+"."+octetStr.Substring(4, 4)+"."+octetStr.Substring(8);
```